# IIS - How to mask a domain name to a specific page in another domain

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, url-rewrite-module, arr

Let say if the URL provided to users is

http://domainA.com

I need to redirect users to

https://domainB.com/page1.aspx

By having users still see https://domainA.com/page1.aspx in the address bar.

Then any links on page1.aspx must have domainA.com as domain name in URLs.
Users should see the links like below links on page1.aspx

https://domainA.com/page2.aspx

https://domainA.com/page3.aspx

page1.aspx, page2.aspx, and page3.aspx are actually hosted on https://domainB.com

How could I achieve this? URLRewrite? ARR? How many rules do I need to set this?

Comment: One ugly solution could be using `iframe` but it could be partial full fill you objective.

Comment: You can create a Forward Proxy Using Application Request Routing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing

Answer (score 0):

To serve content from another domain you will need to **configure IIS as a reverse proxy**:

1. Install [*Application Request Routing (ARR)*](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)
2. Click *Server Proxy Settings*
3. Check *Enable proxy*
4. Set *HTTP Version* to *Pass through*

Comment: Looks like Microsoft also has a [Reverse Proxy Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-rule-template) that may be useful.